# Difference between CSV files which makes different outcome using getline()

Tags: c++, csv

I'm writing a function which reads a CSV file using getline() and converts data to the vector of vectors. To test it I've tried to read two files with the same delimiter: one imported from the internet and second exported from R datasets. The first few lines of each looks like:

File1.csv

```
User ID,Category 1,Category 2,Category 3,Category 4,Category 5,Category 6,Category 7,Category 8,Category 9,Category 10
User 1,0.93,1.8,2.29,0.62,0.8,2.42,3.19,2.79,1.82,2.42
User 2,1.02,2.2,2.66,0.64,1.42,3.18,3.21,2.63,1.86,2.32
User 3,1.22,0.8,0.54,0.53,0.24,1.54,3.18,2.8,1.31,2.5
User 4,0.45,1.8,0.29,0.57,0.46,1.52,3.18,2.96,1.57,2.86
```

File2.csv

```
"","Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"
"1",5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
"2",4.9,3,1.4,0.2
"3",4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
"4",4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2
```

However getline() works only for the first one. In second case it simply returns white space. The function performs similar even if I copy single lines from one file to another (of course adding or removing additional colums) -- the rows from file1 will be always properly read while those from file2 never. I've even tried removing " chars, but without much improvement. However switching from comas to '\t' solves the problem.

I'm curious what's the difference between those two files that makes such different outcome?

The source code of my function:

```
vector<vector<string>> readData(string fileName,int firstLine,char delimeter){
    //Open data file
    fstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName, ios::in);

    //Data stored in 2d vector of strings
    vector<vector<string>> data;
    vector<string> row;
    string line,word,temp;
    //Read data
    int i=0;
    while(fin>>temp){
        row.clear();
        //Read line and store in 'line'
        getline(fin,line);
        //Don't read first n lines
        if (i<firstLine){
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<line<<endl;
        //Break words
        stringstream s(line);
        //Read every column and store in in 'word;
        while(getline(s,word,delimeter)){
            row.push_back(word);
        }
        //Append row to the data vector
        data.push_back(row);
    }
    //Close file
    fin.close();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(fin>>temp){
        row.clear();
        //Read line and store in 'line'
        getline(fin,line);
```

`fin >> temp` reads everything till the first space or newline. It is not clear why you do that as only with `getline(fin,line)` you then try to read the full line and you are not using `temp`. In the first file `fin>>temp` consumes only "User", in the second file it consumes the full line, because there are no spaces.

If you look at the read data from the first file you will also notice that the first part of each line is missing.

Tip: Use more meaningful names for your variables. I didn't manage to fully understand your logic, because variables named `s` and the presence of `row` and `line` at the same time causes me headaces.

Comment: Looks like "you shouldn't mindlessly copy code from the internet". Thank you very much!

Comment: @Polonius never. "it works" means nothing, you always need to understand why it works. Sometimes code that works but you dont know why requires debugging that is more difficult than debugging code that is broken